# Asp.net 4.0 c# membership user image

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, authentication

What I want to extract from the database is the UserImage in the table aspnet_Users but how do I extract it?

I know when I want to extract the username its simply just by

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    lblUserName.Text = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

And how do I convert an image to byte[]?

Or can I simply just add a new column and how will i be able to extract that 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advise will be for to use profiles to store unique information per user in your case it is an image path but store image file may be on CDN and your second question : **And how do I convert an image to byte[]?**

```
    System.Drawing.Image userImage = new Bitmap(ImagePath);

    System.IO.MemoryStream imageMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    userImage.Save(imageMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    byte[] ImageByteArray = imageMemoryStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: But what if I want to add a new column with the image path how will I be able to extract it for exactly that username?